# SSIS active log transaction issue

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, transaction-log

I have 13 different table to import to different server and each table there are about 30 millions records and including one which has 90 million records. I tried one load for one table in SSIS for 50 million of data and this was completed in an hour. 
if I put them all in one package but in different dataflow and one completed after another, will there be any issue with the Active log transaction error?
will the log be active till the package is complete or will be refreshed after each dataflow is done?